Removing $id from json file
I have response from Json and it included the $id, is there a way to remove the schema stuff from the response:
Using .Net Core for this API.
{
  "$id": "1",
  "id": "d84935e9-e670-4bb7-99b2-603cda508701",

Thanks in advance

The question lacks a lot of details. Are you the one creating the JSON response or are you just consuming it? If you're just consuming it, you can just omit the ID property from your modal (assuming you have an appropriate DTO).

With limited knowledge of your project, I think the $id part might be coming from the default Json behavior.
Can you check your service configuration where you're registering services? If you have something like
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        // This generates the $id field to handle circular reference problems
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
    });

or if you're using Newtonsoft.Json
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => 
    {
        opts.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    });

A circular reference occurs when objects in a model refer back to each other, forming a loop.
You can choose to ignore circular references, which will prevent the creation of $id fields. When a loop is detected, the serializer will assign null to the object that caused the loop.
To do this, you can configure it like this in System.Text.Json,
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    });

or in Newtonsoft.Json
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });

hope it helps,
